# Trying to use brace expansion in EOF heredoc

Tags: bash, awk, eof

I am trying to use brace expansion in an EOF heredoc. Having a lot of trouble doing so. I am trying to create a script which will tell the person their chinese zodiac, and it's based on year/month/day 
example: Feb 2 1984 - Feb 19 1985 = RAT

```
awk -v year="${1}${2}${3}" '
$0 ~ year {
    print $1
    found = 1
    exit
}
END {
    if (!found)
        exit 1
}
' <<EOF
Rat 1984 1985 1996 2008 2020 2034
Ox  1985 1997 2009 2021
Tiger 1986 1998 2010 2022
Rabbit 1987 1999 2011 2023
Dragon 1988 2000 2012 2024
Snake 1989 2001 2013 2025
Horse 1990 2002 2014 2026
Goat 1991 2003 2015 2027
Monkey 1992 2004 2016 2028
Rooster 1993 2005 2017 2029
Dog 1994 2006 2018 2030
Pig 1995 2007 2019 2031
EOF
```

I would like to use Rat 1984{02..12}{0..31} 1985{01,02}{0..31} in order to expand my awk to search through the range of numbers provided in the brace. Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a search for this? Just get `year % 12` and use that as an index into an array.

Comment: Why do you have 1985 in the Rat row? 1985 was Ox.

Comment: It is an error Barmar, the problem is stated above. There are ranges of days that I must account for, year % 12 will work just fine, but I cannot account for the days. If you have a suggestion it is most welcome, here is the file I have to work with. https://scs.senecac.on.ca/~azzad.kara/subjects/ops435-143/ChineseZodiac.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bash manual on [here documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) says:

> If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

The *word* in your sample is the unquoted `EOF`.

The list of expansions does not include [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion); I think you are out of luck.

---

> Is there a workaround?

It may depend in part on your version of Bash — on macOS Sierra 10.12.4, the default is 3.2.57, which gives different output from Bash 4.3.

Brace expansion is a somewhat limited affair — there are many things you can't do with it because variables are not expanded until after brace expansion occurs.

This might be a hint; I'm not quite sure how you'd include it in your script, though.

```
$ printf 'Rat %s\n' 1984{02..12}{0..31} 1985{01,02}{0..31}
Rat 198420
Rat 198421
Rat 198422
Rat 198423
Rat 198424
…
Rat 19850227
Rat 19850228
Rat 19850229
Rat 19850230
Rat 19850231
$ bash-4.3 -c "printf 'Rat %s\n' 1984{02..12}{0..31} 1985{01,02}{0..31}"
Rat 1984020
Rat 1984021
Rat 1984022
Rat 1984023
Rat 1984024
Rat 1984025
…
Rat 19850226
Rat 19850227
Rat 19850228
Rat 19850229
Rat 19850230
Rat 19850231
$
```

Note that the leading zeros are gone in 198420, etc. with Bash 3.x.  I'm curious about day 0, not to mention 31st February, but I assume those will be dealt with.

Now you have to decide how you might incorporate that into your script to generate the data.  You might find that a script that generates a script, and then runs the generated script, is easier to manage than scripting directly.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that and I was wondering if there is a work-around. I can always make variables that contain the range.. although I am not sure if it will work correctly.

Comment: you can use something like `$(seq -s" " 02 12)` if i'm getting you right. which will expand to `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`

Comment: I'll give it a shot, didn't think of seq. This is for a bash class and my teacher doesn't like seq (don't ask why), but ... expletive him :D

Comment: Jonathan I appreciate the time you took to answer my question. I think with 12 printf statements like that I can generate everything I need for this script. Thank you very much!